# Firebase gives "ERROR error [object Object]" when trying to upload file

Tags: javascript, firebase, file-upload, blob, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload an image to Firebase storage but it's hitting me with a highly-descriptive `ERROR Error: "[object Object]"`.

My file is being read in like this:

```
previewImage(image) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(image.files[0])
    reader.onload = (event) => {
      this.image = event.target.result;
    }
  }
```

And then being sent to a service like this:

```
    this.db.addToBucket(`images/profiles/${this.user.id}.png`, this.image)
```

In the service, I try to upload it like this:

```
addToBucket(path, file) {
    console.log(path);
    this.storage.ref(path).put(file).then(function(snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot);
    })
  }
```

So, the reference should work out as something like `images/profiles/1.png`. The file should be a base64 object, which seems to be what the documentation requests. I don't really know how this whole process works, so I've also included the base64 image itself (the entire thing), although I think only start is necessary. You can find it in [pastebin here.](https://pastebin.com/tTy3Pqna)

I get the distinct feeling that this is just a simple misuse of the API and nothing greater but I really have no idea what could cause this. For reference, when I log the path, it comes out as `images/profiles/12968216.png` which is correct for my needs, but nothing exists in storage at that location yet. I have the folders created, but no image there yet.

Comment: You should try to catch and print the error using ```console.log(JSON.stringify(error))```

Comment: @Nenroz Sorry, but I don't know how to do that. I tried doing a `.catch()` after the `.then()` but the method seems to error anyway and never hits the catch block.